# How do you turn a kotlinx.html widget into a string?

Tags: kotlinx-html

In the kotlinx.html documentation, it talks building "widgets" (where a widget is just some of the html dsl) like this:

```
@HtmlTagMarker
fun FlowContent.widget(body: FlowContent.() -> Unit) {
  div { body() }
}
```

How would you turn that into html if you didn't want to wrap it in a body?  It's clear how you would get it wrapped in something else:

```
createHTML().body {
  widget { +"stuff" }
}
```

gets you

```
<body>
  <div>stuff</div>
</body>
```

But what's the right way to just get the `<div>stuff</div>` without wrapping it in something?

Answer (score 0):

According to (not-so-easy-to-discover) [official documentation](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.html/wiki/Micro-templating-and-DSL-customizing#introduce-custom-tag):

> If you want it to be available on the root (like this: `appendHTML().custom { }`) you have to declare it on `TagConsumer`

So to make your example work you need:

```
fun <T> TagConsumer<T>.widget(block: FlowContent.() -> Unit): T =
    div { block() }
```

And using it will give you expected result:

```
val html = createHTML()
    .widget { +"Hello" }
    .toString()

assert html == "<div>Hello</div>"
```